# How to convert text DateTime containing spaces to YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS in SSiS

Tags: sql, ssis

| Date |  | required Format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/8/2020 08:20 |  | 2020-08-01 8-20-00 |
| 2/8/2020 9:20 |  | 2020-8-02 9-20-00 |
| 1/8/2020 08:23 |  | 2020-08-01 8-23-00 |

Comment: SSIS is not the same as MySQL, both of which have nothing to do with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a derived column expression to change the data type to the desired format using [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
(
(DT_STR,4000,1252)
(
LEFT(TOKEN(date ,"/",1),4) 
+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN(date ,"/",2),2) 
+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN(date ,"/",3),2) 
+ " " +
+ " " + TOKEN(date ,":",4)
+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN(date ,":",5),2) 
+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN(date ,":",6),2)
)
)
```

I'm not sure about your time format, as you don't have a running zero before your time format so you might need to adjust the above code to your specific needs.

Edited: Would have asked questions first if I am able to comment on the question.